# How can I make my bot react to a message I sent?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made a help command, I want my bot to react to the '?help' message with a green tick that a user sends. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sent message in a variable, and you can either use unicode, or (if your IDE supports it) you can also paste the emoji itself.

```py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Here's some text!")
    await msg.add_reaction("\u2705") # or just directly paste in ✅
```

And if it's a custom emoji:

```py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Some more text!")
    emoji = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.emojis, name="emojiNameHere")
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

In addition to searching by its name, you can also search via its ID which you can see if you type `\:emojiName:` in discord and send it:

```py
emoji = bot.get_emoji(112233445566778899)
# same concept can apply in utils.get - just search with id= instead of name=
```

---

**References:**

- [Find emoji unicodes here](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_emoticons.html)
- [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Client.get_emoji()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_emoji)